# React-Native: jest error with function findNodeHandle

Tags: react-native, mocking, jestjs

I'm having a problem with `findNodeHandle` of the package `react-native` when i runs jest.
My code is this:

```
import { findNodeHandle, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default class Input extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        findNodeHandle(this.refInput);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                ref={ref => this.refInput = ref}
            />
        )
    }
```

when i runs the jest, it show this error:

```
    Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

at invariant (node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:44:15)
at findCurrentFiberUsingSlowPath (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:562:8)
at findCurrentHostFiber$1 (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:609:19)
at Object.findHostInstance (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3078:15)
at Object.<anonymous>.injectedFindNode (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3236:33)
at findNodeHandle (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3246:25)
at findNumericNodeHandleFiber (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/ReactNativeFiber-dev.js:3250:14)
```

I'm was think in mock the package `react-native` and treat the function `findNodeHandle`, but I could not find a way to make that mock.

How could i resolve this?

react-native: 49.5
jest: 21.2.1

thanks

Comment: Where is `refInput`? I didn't see that in your code

Comment: @Val i edited and added the component with the `refInput`.

Comment: Why are you using `findNodeHandle` on `<TextInput />`? It's designed to work on native component only. (bridge native code interface to react interface)